# using a Cursor to get sqllite data

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am trying to get some data using a cursor but I dont really know if I am doing it right as the row and column of data I am trying to get is returning null.

Here is where I am storing the data:

```
   JSONArray badges = jsonObject.getJSONArray("badges");
            Log.i("badges length:",  badges.length() + "");
            for(int i = 0; i < badges.length(); i++){
                JSONObject currentBadge = badges.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("badge image_url:",  currentBadge.getString("image_url") + "");
                db.updateBadgesRecord(i, currentBadge.getString("id"), currentBadge.getString("name"), currentBadge.getString("description"), currentBadge.getString("image_url"), currentBadge.getString("club_id"), currentBadge.getString("created_at"));
            }
```

the Log.i shows that there is 18 objects(rows).

Here is the updateBadgesRecord function:

```
public boolean updateBadgesRecord(long rowId, String id, String name, String description, String image_url, String club_id, String created_at) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        if(id != null){
        args.put(KEY_BADGES_ID, id);
        }
        if(name != null){
        args.put(KEY_BADGES_NAME, name);
        }
        if(description != null){
        args.put(KEY_BADGES_DESCRIPTION, description);
        }
        if(image_url != null){
        args.put(KEY_BADGES_IMAGEURL, image_url);
        }
        if(club_id != null){
        args.put(KEY_BADGES_CLUBID, club_id);
        }
        if(created_at != null){
        args.put(KEY_BADGES_CREATEDAT, created_at);
        }

        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE_BADGES, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
```

I THINK it is storing but I am not sure. This is how I am trying to display it:

```
public void activateBadgeList(){
        for(int i = 0; i < badgeButtons.length; i++){
            if(true){
            badgeButtons[i].setActivated(true);
            badgeButtons[i].setAlpha(1.0f);
            db.open();


            Cursor c = db.getBadgeRecord(i);
            String image_url = null;
            if (c.moveToFirst()){
                   while(!c.isAfterLast()){
                      image_url = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BADGES_IMAGEURL));
                      // do what ever you want here
                      c.moveToNext();
                   }
                }
                c.close();
            if(image_url != null){
            Log.i("image url", image_url);
            } else {
            Log.e("image url", "image url is null");    
            }
            badgeButtons[i] = UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(badgeButtons[i], image_url);
            db.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

badgeButtons length is 16 so I know that I can populate the badges easily.... However.... the image url is returning null (which prints "image url is null 18 times in my console"). Here is my getBadgeRecord function:

```
public Cursor getBadgeRecord(long rowId) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_BADGES, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_BADGES_ID, KEY_BADGES_NAME, KEY_BADGES_DESCRIPTION, KEY_BADGES_IMAGEURL, KEY_BADGES_CLUBID, KEY_BADGES_CLUBID}, 
            KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help! I am a newbie.

Thankyou!

Comment: SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); have you initialized db. if not try this in getBadgeRecord

Comment: did not change anything. I have a function called open() where I call getWritableDatabase().

Comment: I would check that the updateBadgesRecord is actually getting a non-null imageUrl to insert in the first place. Also just to debug try calling 'DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRowToString(Cursor c)' to see what's actually in the cursor..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is being retrieved correctly so the answer to my question is actually within the question itself as it is a correct method to get the data. The problem was that db.update(...) only updates existing rows. do db.insert(...) before hand.

Answer (score 0):

"What am I doing wrong" is a broad request, but here are two things:

1. If you are going to have a constant for column name, use it!  What does `KEY_BADGES_IMAGEURL` equal?  I don't know, but when you want to find what is stored in that column via `cursor`, you'd better be using

   ```
   image_url = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BADGES_IMAGEURL));
   ```

instead of:

```
  image_url = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("image_url"));
```

1. When making queries, you should be using ?'s and supplied parameters.  These get stored in the `SQLite` cache for looking things up, and you reduce performance by not using parameters.

Also, this line should use parameters instead of

`KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowID`, it should be `KEY_ROWID + "=?"` and use a parameter.

Comment: I think HaIR means change this line: "db.update(DATABASE_TABLE_BADGES, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null)" to "db.update(DATABASE_TABLE_BADGES, args, KEY_ROWID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(rowId)})"

Comment: Yes danielgrech, that is what I was implying.

Comment: Ok i tried that and I am still getting a cursor record count of 0 on the query with syntax: db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_BADGES, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_BADGES_ID, KEY_BADGES_NAME, KEY_BADGES_DESCRIPTION, KEY_BADGES_IMAGEURL, KEY_BADGES_CLUBID, KEY_BADGES_CREATEDAT}, 
                KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null); rowId at the moment as been tested on 0, 1, 2, 3...16